# Heron Algorithm Recursive C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to implement the heron algorithm recursively in C#.
I don't really understand where my code is wrong:

Given definition of algorithm:

```
x[n+1] = (p-1) /p*x[n] + a/p*x[n]^p-1
Where xo = 1 and p root a
```

```cs
public static double Heron(int x,int p,int a)
{
    if(x == 0)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }

    return ((p-1.0)/p)*Heron(--x,p,a)+a/(p*Math.Pow(Heron(--x,p,a),--p));

}
```

e.g Heron(1,3,5) should return 7/3;

Comment: Dont use `--x` but use `x-1` instead. Same for `--p`.

Comment: `Heron(1,3,5)` will return `0` since `x=1` and this is your terminal condition.

Comment: @JAlex Thanks! Changing to x-1 and p-1 solved my problem

Comment: Do you understand why using `--x` is a bad idea? It modifies the value and  you wrote it down twice and so the second time it evaluates it uses the modified value.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this algorithm, but want to point out that `((p-1.0)/p)*<something>` is not the same as `p-1/p*<something>`.

Comment: @500 Perhaps the algo is expressed in some simple pseudocore form that does pure left to right rather than precedence.. but it's a useful point!

Comment: @500-InternalServerError you're right I just forgot the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify the value of `x` and `p` in your expression.

Just use

```
double x_n = Heron(x-1,p,a);
return ((p-1.0)/p)*x_n+a/(p*Math.Pow(x_n,p-1));
```

I have also kept the value of the recursion in `x_n` so it does not get called twice.